# How to enable Android Target option in Xamarin Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin. I installed Visual studio in my Mac and successfully link the android sdk and jdk but still Android target is disabled in new project window please see the below screenshots.

[image: Android SDK PATH] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Xamrin needs Android.NDK to communicate between its C#/.Net code and native Java code. Therefore, you need to download Android NDK, then set it up in Settings just like in your first photo and everything will work just fine.

Below is settings from my IDE:

[image]